# How to copy a OpenGL External Texture (GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES) to a Framebuffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I need to copy the texture to a framebuffer and then read it using GlReadPixels and save the output to a buffer. The main goal is to dump the input frames of exoplayer into a file. My current code gives me glx506 error.

```
int[] frame = new int[1];
int[] mainFrame = new int[1];
glGetIntegerv(GLES32.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, mainFrame,0);

GLES32.glGenFramebuffers(1,frame,0);
GlUtil.checkGlError("glGenFramebufferOES");

GLES11Ext.glBindFramebufferOES(GLES11Ext.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, frame[0]);
GlUtil.checkGlError("glBindFramebufferOES");

GLES11Ext.glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GLES11Ext.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,GLES11Ext.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GLES32.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture,0);
GlUtil.checkGlError("glFramebufferTexture2DOES");

GLES11Ext.glBindFramebufferOES(GLES11Ext.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, frame[0]);
GlUtil.checkGlError("glBindFramebufferOES");

GLES32.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
GlUtil.checkGlError("glViewport");


ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);

GLES32.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES32.GL_RGBA,GLES32.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
GlUtil.checkGlError("glReadPixels");

File file = new File("/sdcard/Movies/frames/input_"+mediaTime+".rgba");
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.toString());
  FileChannel fch = fos.getChannel();
  fch.write(buffer);
  fch.close();
  fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d(TAG, "Saved input frame : Dimensions : " + width + "x" + height + " Frame saved as '" + file + "'");

GLES11Ext.glBindFramebufferOES(GLES11Ext.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, mainFrame[0]);
GLES32.glViewport(0, 0, mWindowSurface.getWidth(), mWindowSurface.getHeight());
```